Role-Based Authorization in .Net 8 using AD
I am developing a Web Application using Blazor - Server Side that everytime they open the web app, it will run the authorization if the person has an AD or not.
If i run the program using IIS Express, it runs fine and there are no problems. But if I add it to the test server, it will get an error:

Error: There was an unhandled exception on the current circuit, so this circuit will be terminated. For more details turn on detailed exceptions by setting 'DetailedErrors: true' in 'appSettings.Development.json' or set 'CircuitOptions.DetailedErrors'.

I have this code to get the AD of the user:
public class CustomAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly IAppUserRepository _appUserRepository;
    public CustomAuthStateProvider(IAppUserRepository appUserRepository)
    {
        _appUserRepository = appUserRepository;
    }
    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var userName = GetCurrentUserName();
        var fullName = await GetFullName();
        var role = await GetCurrentUserRoleAsync();
        if (userName is not null)
        {
            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, fullName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role),
            };

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Windows Authentication");
        var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        return new AuthenticationState(user);
    }
    else
    {
        return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal());
    }
}

public string GetCurrentUserName()
{
    var loggedUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

    string? userName = loggedUser.Name;

    userName = userName?.Replace("\\", "/");

    int slash = userName.LastIndexOf('/');

    return slash >= 0 ? userName.Substring(slash + 1) : userName;
}

public async Task<string> GetFullName()
{
    var userName = GetCurrentUserName();
    var adUser = await _appUserRepository.GetUserFullname(userName);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(adUser))
    {
        return $"not registered({adUser})";
    }
    return adUser;
}

public async Task<string> GetCurrentUserRoleAsync()
{
    var userName = GetCurrentUserName();
    var role = await _appUserRepository.GetUserRoleAsync(userName);
    return role;
}

Even though the userName, fullName, and role is not empty/null, it errors.
Does anyone have an idea as to what the problem is?
